# Change Form Single Select element to Multi Select for JS enabled users

Tags: forms, javascript, views

I would like to have an exposed filter that shows single select by default, but for JS users is able to be altered to a multi-select.

The reason for this is that I want to apply the JQuery plugin [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) onto my multi-select elements. However showing the pure multi-select element in the same block space on the page will be both unsightly and unwieldy for non-JS users, so I'd prefer they fell back to a single-select drop down menu.

I guess I can easily change a single select to a multi-select using JQuery, however is this going to prevent Drupal from accepting multiple values since the form element will only be expecting a single value for that single-select element?

Thank!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like someone made a module for this: http://drupal.org/project/chosen, maybe he can provides some support for views.

Some details from the module's project page:

> Chosen uses the [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) jQuery plugin to make your `<select>` elements more user-friendly.